# load xib view in storyboard. why do we have to do self.addSubview(nibView) ?

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, xib

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    guard let view = loadViewFromNib() else { return }
    view.frame = self.bounds
    self.addSubview(view) // My question
}

func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView? {
    let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
    let nib = UINib(nibName: self.className, bundle: bundle)
    return nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as? UIView
}
```

i want customXibView initial with nib .look like self = loadViewFromNib(), not by self.addSubview(nibView) .

I found that many of the answers are all done self.addSubview(nibView). In fact, look our view hierarchy,we will found a extra view.
[This is my view hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxR5B.png)

Is there any way to instance xib to storyboard, not by self.addSubview(nibView).

if you don't understand my question,look this [Custom UIView from Xib - requirements, good practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49480436). I hope some one help me.

Answer (score 0):

There are three scenarios:

1. You have `CustomView` class with all of its UI defined
   programmatically in its drawRect method.
2. You have `CustomView` class with its UI defined in a subview of storyboard scene with its class set to '`CustomView`'.
3. You have `CustomView` class with its UI defined in a separate xib.

Now if you want to include your CustomView in as a subview in your viewcontroller, the method differs depending how your class is defined in the first instance. Secondly how do you want to include it in you viewcontroller.

**Adding CustomView with scenario 1:**

Initialise the CustomView instance in your viewDidLoad method and add it to your viewcontroller's view as a subview.

**Adding CustomView with condition 2:**

You don't have to do anything in this scenario. Storyboards will initizlize your class for you. You can do additional setup in init(coder) method that will be called when you view is initialized.

**Adding CustomView with condition 3:**

The proper way to initialise a view with an xib is to initialise it programmatically via UINib's `inistantiateWithOwner` method. Then add the view as a subview in the `viewDidLoad` method of your viewcontroller.

What you are doing (or what I can guess seeing your image hierarchy) is that you have changed the class of your `UIView` to your custom class. Now since you have a separate xib, you are initialising it in `init(coder)` method and adding it as a subview to the view that was defined in and initialised by the storyboard. Hence you end up with an extra container view.

If you don't want the extra view, add your custom view programmatically.

OR

(If possible) copy the view defined in xib and place it in the viewcontroller dock and then link the view with an outlet and add it in `viewDidLoad` method.

Comment: Yes, i don't want the extra view.

Comment: The above two methods really avoid generating extra views. But is there really no better way? Load xib to storyboard and don't creat a extra view.

Comment: No, I am afraid there isn't. If you have your view with an xib, you cannot add it using storyboards without an extra (wrapper) view. This is the tradeoff.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer you've wanted all along. You can just create your `CustomView` class, have the master instance of it in a xib with all the subviews and outlets. Then you can apply that class to any instances in your storyboards or other xibs.

No need to fiddle with File's Owner, or connect outlets to a proxy or modify the xib in a peculiar way, or add an instance of your custom view as a subview of itself (i.e. no need for `self.addSubview(view)`, which is your question).

Just do this:

1. Import BFWControls framework
2. Change your superclass from `UIView` to `NibView` (or from `UITableViewCell` to `NibTableViewCell`)

That's it!

It even works with IBDesignable to refer your custom view (including the subviews from the xib) at design time in the storyboard.

You can read more about it here:
https://medium.com/build-an-app-like-lego/embed-a-xib-in-a-storyboard-953edf274155

And you can get the open source BFWControls framework here:
https://github.com/BareFeetWare/BFWControls

And here's a simple extract of the `NibReplaceable` code that drives it, in case you're curious: https://gist.github.com/barefeettom/f48f6569100415e0ef1fd530ca39f5b4

Tom

Answer (score -1):

Its not necessary that you have to add the xib view as subview. Think about the usage, as per my understanding there are tow scenarios

Suppose you have a view called `customXibView` class and its xib, now in the xib select the view and and from the right side panel select [identity inspector] option and check, under [custom class] by default its class is `UIView`. So you can keep it as `UIView` and set the file owner as `customXibView` and load it from xib as `UIView` instance as you are doing now. So, now the question is if you allocate `customXibView` object manually or in some other xib how it will show your custom components which are in your view xib. So in that case in your `customXibView's` `init` method you have to load the `UIView` xib and add it to `customXibView`object's view.

Another case where you can set the xib's view [custom class] as your class `customXibView` in this case when you call the below method

```
func loadViewFromNib() -> customXibView? {
    let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
    let nib = UINib(nibName: self.className, bundle: bundle)
    return nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as? customXibView
}
```

You directly get an object of `customXibView` with UI loaded no need to add it to any other view. But in this case if you allocate the `customXibView` class object your UI will not be loaded if you don't do what what you are doing now. If any doubt plz comment.

Comment: I don't want to add XibView to self( just like : self.addSubview(xibView) ). How to load the customXibView in storyboard directly?

Comment: I load xibView in storyboard or another xib. I will get more View. I think its not necessary in the view hierarchy. [look this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxR5B.png)